# Commit Operation Failed in SVN in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am trying to checkin the project in to SVN repository. So I right click on the project then selected Team then Commit. And when I do commit I get--

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Working copy 'C:\workspace\crawler4j\target' is missing or not locked
```

Any suggestions how to overcome this will be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, it's simply easier to open a Subversion command line client and take a look at that. I suggest that you install a command line client, go to the directory, and do a `svn status`. I would also look at `svn info` on the various directories and files and make sure they're all on the same working directory. (You can do a `svn status -v` to get that information).

My feeling is that the `target` directory should not be added or have been added to your project. This directory in Maven is used for built objects which should not be committed into your Subversion repository. Even many Ant build scripts follow Maven in this.

So, what is the status of the `target` directory? What happens when you do an update on the directory before committing your changes? (I believe it's `Team->Update`).

Answer (score 0):

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/PluginFAQ#head-73584410a8d4fbad6781c7b16be39f6518410a61 here you can find the solution

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Kepler try to run Team>cleanup